# Fujitsu Lifebook NH532 screen dimmed catastrophically after Nvidia driver update

Tags: windows-8, display, display-driver

I have a one year old Fujitsu lifebook NH532 laptop running Windows 8. Recently I updated the driver for the Nvidia graphics card from version 331.82 to 335.23 WHQL and on installation the laptop screen turned black. When I turned on the computer, the screen continues to be very dark (with no brightness) even at BIOS boot time. If I placed my laptop next to sunlight, I can see the heavily dimmed screen booting to Windows 8 and I can log on. I can do whatever I like though it is very difficult to navigate and I have now set the screen brightness to maximum but to no avail as the screen is still dark. I have tried several things:

1. Booting in safe mode but the screeen remains dark;
2. Restoring an earlier system image but the screen remains dark;
3. Trying to install a new Windows 8 OS but the screen remains dark;
4. Using a third party software to put the screen brighness in Windows to maximum but the screen still remains dark;
5. Removing all Nvidia drivers but without any change;
6. Putting the version 305.46 of Nvidia that comes with the drivers DVD from Fujitsu but without any change (same version is on Support site);
7. Upating the BIOS from version 2.04 to the latest version 2.08 using the driver from Fujitsu Support site but that didn't help.

The Graphics card is the Nvidia GEForce GT 640M LE.

There is also the Intel HD graphics display driver on my laptop which I tried to unistall and reinstall but there is no change.

Fujitsu forums have not given me anything tangible. Has the Nvidia update affected the screen's backlight somehow?

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: Try plugging another monitor to your notebook and press Win+P+P. Do you see the image in second monitor?

Comment: @Jet Thanks. I will try this in a couple of days when I'll have access to another monitor. Is it Win+P or Win+P+P? So we press Win and simultaneously P and then P again?

Comment: Yes, keep Win pressed then press P twice (because if you press Win+P nothing will change). I think it's a hardware problem, not software/driver problem (because reinstalling OS didn't help). Probably you have damaged the screen.

Comment: I remember I had the same problem with my notebook some years ago (but not the same notebook). I disassembled it, checked pins and assembled it back, and It worked. But if you want to disassemble, first google how to disassemble it (for not damaging it). [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqE9-rjuYZk) is a video which I got after a minute of searching. But, yes, check if it doesn't work with another monitor then disassemble.

Comment: @Jet Plugging into another monitor works fine. You mentioned that it can be a hardware problem. But this problem arose during the **update** of the Nvidia drivers after which my screen dimmed. So there are no physical damages involved. Can a fuse or the inverter be damaged somehow?

Comment: I don't think that driver update can cause it. But to make it clear, try to boot from a Live CD. If it remains dark, then surely it's a hardware problem. For example, you can use [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) installation disk which has built-in live distro, easy-to-use. Or any other bootable media can do the job.

Comment: You said that you tried to reinstall Windows 8. You installed it from disk/usb or from HDD? Was the screen OK while installation process?

Comment: @Jet I believe that the driver update can only cause software problems and not hardware ones! But I am not an expert. As I mentioned, it was the driver update which caused the problem and nothing else. Yes I used a Win 8 DVD and win 7 DVD to try reinstalling the OS. But even so, the screen remained dimmed during the installation process. This is strange as I thought that generic display drivers would be loaded in the installation process. I've set the laptop to boot last with the HDD.

Comment: @Jet As I've already tried with the Win 8 and 7 DVDs, would it make sense to try the Ubuntu CD/DVD? I don't have a live linux CD/DVD and would have to download one or perhaps I can still get Ubuntu shipped to me freely these days???

Comment: If another monitor worked well and it was dimmed while booting from another DVD then I believe it's a hardware problem. In my case disassembling and assembling notebook helped. I don't know what could happen while updating and it seems strange to me too (because usually driver problems don't get solved by changing monitor).

Comment: What about Ubuntu - it's 970MB ISO so downloading it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (and burning to DVD/USB using tools like [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/downloads)) is a better way. If you have slow internet, you can download official [torrent](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). If Ubuntu (or other Linux distro) doesn't work, then surely it's not a driver/software or Windows problem, it's 100% a hardware problem. (Why I recomend Ubuntu - it has bigger driver database compared to other linux distros.) So if you want, try it and feedback here.

Comment: @Jet A local computer repairs shop has confirmed that the screen is damaged. I don't think that I will replace the screen as there could be something faulty with the motherboard itself which could damage any replacement screen. Perhaps I can look for a docking station and then connect an external monitor to it. This could be a safer option. Later on I will try the Ubuntu option. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late and it turned out to be a hardware issue at the end, but nevertheless I wanted to share my experiences with NH532 because the title of the question is somewhat related:

1. I used to have the "black screen issue" with NH532 after booting up on Windows 8.1. It would only project to the external display, but the laptop screen would remain black. A quick workaround was to press the power button once to put it to sleep, and after resuming it would work fine. **Installing the latest BIOS update** (once it was released on Fujitsu support pages) fixed the issue for Windows 8, 8.1 and later 10.
2. After a certain automatic Windows update, the system wasn't booting up anymore. It turned out that newer NVidia graphics drivers were no longer compatible with this system. I reinstalled the OS, and it immediately downloaded the new driver during installation, again ruining the OS. The solution was finally to install an **older GeForce driver (9.18.13.4725)** and disable automatic hardware updates.